# OpenLayers 6 DragBoxInteraction within limits

Tags: openlayers

I need to select features based on drag box interaction. However in order to limit the number of the selected features I need to restrict the drawn polygon area. Tried with `boxEndCondition` but this as the docs say points when the boxend event will be fired. Are there any options or events I can handle to restrict the width and height of the drawn box area?

```
new DragBoxInteraction({
        condition: platformModifierKeyOnly,
        boxEndCondition: (evnt, startPixel, endPixel) => {
          const width = endPixel[0] - startPixel[0];
          const height = endPixel[1] - startPixel[1];
          const widthAndHeight = width * width + height * height;
          return widthAndHeight >= 65 && widthAndHeight <= 100000;
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use drag box interaction `boxstart` event to record drag start position and map `pointerdrag` event to check if pointer is dragged out of it's limits and in such case then prevent event propagation and default action.

Code could then look something like this (ES5):

```
var dragBoxActive = false;
var dragBoxStartX;
var dragBoxStartY;

map.on('pointerdrag', function(evt) {
  if (dragBoxActive) {
    var width = evt.originalEvent.x - dragBoxStartX;
    var height = evt.originalEvent.y - dragBoxStartY;
    var widthAndHeight = width * width + height * height;
    if (widthAndHeight > 100000) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.preventPropagation();
    }
  }
});

dragBox.on('boxstart', function(evt) {
  dragBoxActive = true;
  dragBoxStartX = evt.mapBrowserEvent.pixel[0];
  dragBoxStartY =  evt.mapBrowserEvent.pixel[1];
});

dragBox.on('boxend', function(evt) {
  dragBoxActive = false;
});
```